# LLVM :- llc: for the --regalloc option: Cannot find option named 'mybasic'

Tags: clang, llvm, clang++, register-allocation

I am trying to clone the basic register allocator of llvm with a customised name 'mybasic'. I have edited all the possible files which contains things related to 'basic' named register allocator. Also, I have built thoroughly without any error. Now, I am unable to figure out why it is still showing this error.
`llc: for the --regalloc option: Cannot find option named 'mybasic'!`

I am on version 12.0.1.

How can I fix the error? Also, I am not able to find enough resources. I will really be grateful if someone helps me with this.
Thanks!